# C# GetResourceSet can't find the default resource resx file

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, resx

I try to load a specific resource set or the default resource set if the specific one is not found.

Here is the code :

```
ResourceSet resourceSet = MyLib.MyResource.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(
    culture: someCulture,
    createIfNotExists: false,
    tryParents: false
);
```

When the specific resx file exist, it works perfectly fine, but for the culture {en}, which is the default one corresponding to the file MyResource.resx it doesn't work (it means ressourceSet =  null)

But if I copy/paste the file "MyResource.resx", and rename it "MyResource.en.resx", then include it in my solution, it suddenly works

My question is: how can I specify that {en} matches the default "MyResource.resx" file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ResourceSet resourceSet = MyLib.MyResource.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(
    culture: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    createIfNotExists: false,
    tryParents: false
);
```

To get more details about `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` please refer to the office documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture